# Why is there no login option for site Y, if I already logged into site X?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, logout, multiple-accounts

**Disclaimer:** I will not use my SE account to upvote or benefit my other account.

I am using Gmail accounts to log in into SE sites.

**Idea:** I am mostly active on the Stack Overflow, *[Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Interpersonal skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour)*, and *[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)* sites. On my Stack Overflow profile, I am using my original name & picture and I have no concerns to do so. But, I want to hide my identity on some sites such as *Interpersonal skills*, *Politics*, etc. I use my nickname and some common picture. This is to post some **very personal issues** for example.

**Problem:** If I already logged into one SE site (Stack Overflow) and opening a new tab in Chrome to log in into another SE site using my second account, I can't see 'log in' option instead 'Join this community'.

This is annoying and inconvenient.

How do I achieve this or am I violating anything here?

Comment: Use a different browser/in private mode/chrome switch user. SE supports only one identity across a single session and applies a single sign on mechanism so that you never have to login on all sites over and over again. By definition this means you don't have to login again nor can you login with a new user. More likely is that those accounts will be happily merged if you tried

Comment: It's like Google. You have one account that you use to log into YouTube, Gmail, docs, etc. If you want to use a different account for one of them, you will have to log out. But that means you will be signed out of all of Google's other products. The solution, as Rene mentioned, is to use a different browser or user profile or incognito mode.

Comment: Actually, this did not solve the problem but understands it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you log into one of our Q&A sites, you're logging into the whole network, not just that one site. Think of it as logging into, for example, Reddit - you log in once, but you can then "subscribe" to individual subreddits. Joining individual Q&A communities is our equivalent of that.

As others mentioned in the comments, if you want to run two separate accounts, you have to either log out or, better yet, use two different browsers or incognito mode to minimize the chances that you forget to log out or something goes wrong, and then have your accounts automatically merged together.

Comment: You can also use separate browser accounts